# IS basicHttpbinding and transport security mutually exclusive?

Tags: wcf, security, https

I need to authenticate a WCF service using windows authentication. I have used the bellow configurations

**End Points at server**

```
<endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Secured" contract="TestWCFSecurity.IService1" address="" />
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingConfiguration="Secured" />
```

**Binding Configurations**

```
<bindings>
 <basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="Secured">
   <security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"  proxyCredentialType="Windows" />
   </security>
  </binding>
 </basicHttpBinding>
</Bindings>
```

While I generate the proxy for the client side, I get the following endpoint

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="https://FQNoftheSystem/TestWCF/Service1.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1"
                contract="IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
</client>
```

**Issues**

1. The client configuration is https, while at the server it is http
   because of which the endpoints do not match. Using "Transport"
   security would mean a https flow.  why am I getting http endpoint at
   the server?
2. I have used basichttpbinding with transport security. is this allowed?
3. using basichttpbinding with transport generates https for client and http at the server.

Any pointers would really help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731092.aspx) `basicHttpBinding` supports transport security.
This seems more like a IIS configuration problem than WCF problem.

[See here for information on how to setup SSL on IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis)

Comment: Thank you @Grzegorz. You are right. basicHttpBinding  and transport security are not mutually exclusive. I have set up SSL in IIS. I am wondering how the service generated is in http and not in https at server side. Any pointers on what could have gone wrong here

Comment: @Nycil I don't get what You mean by "generated an server side"? Didn't you write configuration on Your own?

Comment: Sorry @Grzegorz for the misleading statement. Yes I did write the configuration on my own. I had left the "address" (url)field empty. When I browsed for the service in IIS, the url was http instead of https.